# How can I upload an image to an input field with Nightwatch (currently only uploading text)?

Tags: automated-tests, nightwatch.js

How can I upload an image to an input field using Nightwatch? 
I am currently using `setKeys()` where the Nightwatch code looks like:

```
require('path').resolve(__dirname + '/nightwatch.jpg')
```

However, this results in uploading the text "nightwatch.jpg"

This is what the input field looks like:

```
<input id="cc_action_image_upload" ng-show="true"
  class="btn btn-default btn-file ng-dirty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required next-value"
  ng-class="{'next-value': !nextValid.value || !nextValid.tab2}" type="file"
  ng-file select="onFileSelect($files, 'action_images/', 'action_creative.image')"
  ng-model="uploadFields.actionImage" accept="image/*" name="ls_action_image"
  shown-validation="" valid-file="" required="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);”>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! Small typo in path. I forgot to add `./` before path.